# Flex installation aborted

Tags: apache-flex

Keep getting this message trying to install Apache Flex. 
Happens after Flex wants to know which directory is to hold the installation.
INSTALLATION ABORTED 
Win 8.1 laptop . I follow the instructions.

Please help.Is there a fix to this problem? I select

```
Apache Flex\Apache Flex SDK Installer\newfolder (?)
```

Answer (score 0):

The installation problem is due to one of these 3 reason:

1 - windows security problem : solution : try running the installer as administrator - "run as administrator".

2 - path of installation problem: some folders name are too long : choose a short folder name "in **C:/** for example"

3 - internet connection problem.

The apache flex sdk "installer" is an air application this is not really an installer, it just download choosen parts of apache flex framework - a downloader

Comment: I will try all 3 potential cures. I am highly impressed with the thorough and timely response.